# import and export a jquery function

Tags: jquery, import, ecmascript-6, export

I have a custom.js file with jquery code :

```
$('.nav.navbar-nav > li').on('click', function(e) {
$('.nav.navbar-nav > li').removeClass('active');
$(this).addClass('active');
});
```

I want to export this code to the main.js file.Both files are in the same folder.

Went through the [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/web/javascript/reference/statements/export) but couldn't understand how to do it with jquery.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

First you need to wrap this code in a function. Then you export the function. Finally you import it in main.js:

custom.js

```
export function foo () {
    $('.nav.navbar-nav > li').on('click', function(e) {
        $('.nav.navbar-nav > li').removeClass('active');
        $(this).addClass('active');
    });
}
```

main.js

```
import {foo} from 'custom'

foo();
```

[ECMA SCRIPT 6 modules](http://exploringjs.com/es6/ch_modules.html)

Also notice that you need a module loader (like webpack/systemjs/requirejs etc.), as well as Babel that transpiles your ES6 code to ES5.

Comment: browserify and babel will do the job?

Comment: @ArkadiyStepanov yes they will!

Comment: i have found this example while reading the documentations about browserify 

`var fs = require("fs");
var browserify = require("browserify");
browserify("./script.js")
  .transform("babelify", {presets: ["es2015", "react"]})
  .bundle()
  .pipe(fs.createWriteStream("bundle.js"));`

but i cannot seem to implement it  to my task

`gulp.task('app-scripts', function() {
    return gulp.src('src/js/app.js')
  .pipe(babel({
   presets: ["es2015"]
  }))
        .pipe(uglify())
        .pipe(gulp.dest('build/js'));
});`

Do you have any source that will help me?

Comment: i have already checked it,but it has a lot of things that i dont need,for example `watchify = require('watchify'),`

i am limited only using babelify,babel,browserify and vinyl plugins,

Comment: @ArkadiyStepanov consider using Webpack instead of browserify. It's more complicated but you will find a lot more examples on it combined with Babel