# How to use jQuery to call a JavaScript function from another file

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, function, callback

My question:

I have 2 files:

```
//Sub.js
function Second() {
    //do something here
}

//Main.js
function One() {
    //do something here
}
$(function() {
    Second();
});
```

So basically, the **function Second** is too long; therefore, I want to move it to a **Sub.js** file and call it from the **Main.js**. The problem is this function ( **function Second**) has to be executed after **function One** because it gets some data from the **function One** output.

I don't know how to do this, please help.

Comment: This may be of assistance https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41268431/import-and-export-a-jquery-function.

Comment: There is only function declaration in _main.js_, where are you invoking the method _one()_?

Answer (score 2):

If you specifically want to use jQuery,

```
$.getscript("Sub.js",function(){
   Second();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<script src="/lib/Sub.js"></script>

<script src="/main.js"></script>
```

I think you should initialize firstly **Sub.js** before **main.js** in your head code.

Because whenever the page is first load js are intialize one by one.

Answer (score 0):

You can include both the files in the page and on document ready call it sequentially:

```js
    $( document ).ready(function() {
        var result = first();
        second(result);
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

I was getting a similar problem. My solution was this. I was defining my function inside the .ready() callback. But The problem is that the functions is not accessible outside of its scope. To make this function available in the global scope (or through any object that is available in the global scope) is necessary declare outside the .ready() callback:

Wrong Way:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    function functionName () {
        // ...
    }

    // ...
});
```

Right Way:

```
function functionName () {
    // ...
}

$(document).ready(function() {
    // ...
});
```